# opencv assertion (general)

Tags: c++, opencv

some (most) of opencv errors are discovered in run time - using CV_64 instead of CV_32, accessing out of range, etc. this makes debugging not an easy task, at least when you can't use debug mode from different reasons..
When an error occurs, opencv stops on assert (CV::ASSERT macro)  and tell exactly where in the opencv source it happened.
is there's anyway to tell where that error occurred in the calling code (my code)?
Assuming of course we are in release mode (no break points - only console output)
Thanks

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Comment: What I usually do: `gdb ./program` and there activate `catch throw` to break on opencv assertion fails. `backtrace` will give you the entire stack frames, including the frames related to your code

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Yes**, it's usually easy to tell when OpenCV fails: all you need to do is **check the return of each function call**, and print an error message when a fail occurs.

Comment: Most OpenCV modules don't `throw`. The C and C++ interface of OpenCV uses the return of functions to indicate when an error occurs. Of course, some OpenCV data types are built on top of C++ `std` data types and they may throw for standard operations like vector/arrays stuff.

Comment: true, but:
i.  not all function return true/false on failure (some return value)
ii. it is not feasible to put a try catch block on every opencv usage...
but thanks :)

Comment: We've been working in C++ and errors are definitely caught with assert statements. Most functions return void (ex: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#descriptorextractor-compute). This makes them fairly impenetrable and we've resorted to digging through the source code every time we make an error. If you have suggestions to make this process less painful, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Yes, I have a very good suggestion for making the process MUCH less painful: instead of printing only the location of the error (as currently done, e.g. OpenCV Error: ..... XXX.cpp, line AAA), printing the entire call stack(e.g.: OpenCV Error: ..... XXX.cpp, line AAA, called from YYY.cpp line BBB called from ....). Although it will be messier, This   will give much more informative about the error

Comment: developers.slashdot.org/story/12/12/08/146250/the-scourge-of-error-handling

Comment: "Yes, it's usually easy to tell when OpenCV fails" statement applies if you are an OpenCV developer. I'm trying to stitch two images:

        `Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(false);`
        `Stitcher::Status s = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);`

What I get is:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((globalDescIdx>=0) && (globalDescIdx < size())) in getLocalIdx, file matchers.cpp, line 163
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tbb::captured_exception'

Now I'll have to step through the whole Stitcher class instead of catching an exception and move on.

Comment: "Usually" doesn't mean "everytime". Sorry about that.